# Selecting radio buttons in a row or a column in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have the following markup:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is a 3x3 table with 9 radio buttons in it. I want to configure it so that I can either:

- Select **only 1** radio button per row OR
- Select **only 1** radio button per column

Is this possible without any JavaScript? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the inputs in the rows/columns (Depending on what you want) to have the same name so only one of them will be able to be checked.

## One per row

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## One per column

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```